# Performance, asking mysql to output CSV format vs parsing the results and converting them with the App

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm trying to increase performance on a Node.js App using Mysql as a database.
One feature I'd like to optimize in terms of performance is the repors generator.

Currently the data is being asked to mysql and then the results are parsed in a second time from node.js in a for cycle to then be formatted in CSV format.

My question is: wouldn't be faster to directly query mysql with CSV as output format?

Comment: The simple answer would be to try it on a simple example

Comment: directly query mysql with CSV as output format is faster than formatting in node.js

Comment: I don't think there is a way unless you go inside the module ‍`mysql in npm` itself and manipulate it where it converts the query output to JSON. change output to CSV. To avoid overtime. or using this link : https://bezkoder.com/node-js-export-mysql-csv-file/